# How to edit only selected feature from geojson using leaflet geoman

Tags: leaflet, geojson, reshape, leaflet-geoman, leaflet-draw

I have a GeoJson having 40,000 features as MultiPolygon.Can anyone guide me that how can i select individual polygon from it and edit that selected one. Right now when I click edit in Leaflet-Geoman toolbar it selects all 40,000 features and make them editable that crash browser window.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right your question, you need to filter that objects by property.

Maybe you could send some screenshots or code examples?

You could try to do it like this:

```
let obj = []

if (condition) continue

for (obj in geoJson) {
obj.push(geoJson[obj])
}

console.log(“filtered objects”, obj)
```